# How do I apply the reduction to absurdity rule in the Open Logic natural deduction tool?

Tags: deduction

I'm using the open logic natural deduction tool (https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) as it makes writing proofs very clear and clean but I can't seem to apply the reduction to absurdity rule correctly.

```
Construct a proof for the argument: ¬Q, R → P ∴ (P → Q) → ¬R
        
1   ¬Q      
2   R → P                   
3       P → Q                       
4           R       
5           P           →E 2, 4 
6           Q           →E 3, 5 
7           ¬Q          R 1 
8           Q ∧ ¬Q      ∧I 6, 7 
9       ¬R              ¬I 4–8
```

I think I'm using the rule as stated in the corresponding section of the tool but I get an error message saying "Line 9: Is not a proper application of the rule ¬I (for the line(s) cited)."  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your line 8 can be simply changed to ⊥ (¬E 6, 7), line 9 then changed to ¬R (¬I 4–8), then in line 10 you can arrive at your conclusion (P → Q) → ¬R (→I 3–9) which can be verified quickly in your referenced open logic online tool...

Comment: Thanks! It worked :)

Comment: Now we must listen.

Answer (score 1):

*Open Logic* is an admirable project indeed.

For all those interested, I would like to recommend also [*Stanford Introduction to Logic*](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/) and the [tools therein](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/logica/).
As a sample, I present one with the implementation of *modus tollens*:

[image]